# Transaction Enlist performance issue

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql-server, windows

We have a lengthy database operation. When we perform this operation with enlist = true, it takes 29 minutes to complete. When we perform this operation with enlist = false, it takes only 15 minutes to complete. What is the reason for such a huge performance hit? Is it something related to the database server?

How do we avoid it?  Please share your thoughts.

Database: `SQL Server 2005`

Frameowrk:  `.Net 3.0`

Comment: a: what is the nature of the operation (lots of small executes? one big execute? etc?) and b: is there actually a transaction at the time?

Comment: Total number of rows in a csv file is 100000. These records are to be inserted into a table. We are calling the same stored procedure around 5 times. The parameter is passes as concatenated string to the stored procedure. There will be one big insert having around 20000 records in each iteration of the SP.

Comment: Suggest you post code and maybe even your server/database settings.

Comment: What are the details needed regarding server/database settings?

Comment: @Lijo: might be getting into serverfault.com territory...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do we avoid it?

and

> Total number of rows in a csv file is 100000.

In this case, use `SqlBulkCopy` to write the 100,000 rows into a staging table (a basic and separate table, not part of your transactional tables; no triggers, foreign keys, etc). Once the data is in the staging table, use TSQL (either direct or a SPROC) to do the `INSERT` from the staging table into the *transactional* table, i.e. where your data lives. The transaction only needs to span this last operation.

This achieves several key things:

- `SqlBulkCopy` uses the same API as bulk-insert; it is the fastest way to shift large amounts of data over the wire to SQL Server
- it minimises the size of the transaction, most notably by not including all the data transfer time in the transaction; only the core `INSERT` is transactional, but at this point all the data is local

Comment: Thanks...SQLBulkCopyworks 10 times fatser :-)... Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855871/bulkcopy-from-stored-procedure also