# BulkCopy from Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I have tables A, B and C in database. I have to put the result obtained from A and B into table C.

Currently, I have an SP that returns the result of the A and B to the C# application. This result will be copied into table C using "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy". The advanatge is during the insert using bulkcopy, log files are not created.

I want to avoid this extra traffic, by handling the insert in the SP itself. However, it should not be using any log files. Any way to achieve this?

Please share your thoughts.

**Volume Of Data**: 150,000

**Database** : SQL Server 2005

The database is in  full recovery model; it cannot be changed.. Is **SELECT INTO** usefull in such scenario?

EDIT: When I use System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy, the operation is getting completed in 3 mnutes; in normal insert it takes 30 minutes... This particular operation need not be recovered; however other operations in the database has to be recoveed - hence I cannot change the recovery mode of the whole database.

Thanks

Lijo

Comment: How much data are you looking to insert? Size/Volume

Comment: There's something that doesn't make sense to me here: you're looking to do something to minimize logging, but you say you're in FULL recovery mode - doesn't that mean that even bulk-logged operations (SqlBulkCopy, BULK INSERT, etc) are fully logged anyway? Wouldn't you need to be in the "Bulk Logged" recovery model for this to work as you want?

Comment: IIRC `SELECT INTO` does something very different - creating tables etc

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you need to change your recovery model - I'm just saying the difference you're seeing is probably NOT whether the operations are being logged, but rather something else about the SqlBulkCopy vs INSERT INTO approaches you've used (if your DB really is using the full recovery model). Could be related to locking/blocking, or could be that you were trying to do something in a loop (RBAR) before rather than a single insert??

Comment: I was getting the exception "Insufficient system memory in resource pool 'default' to run this query" when i was running it as a single insert. To reolve this I splitted it and used a loop which will run 5 times. Though it was completing the operation, it was taking 30 mins to complete. (This long time happens only in one DB server; when I tested with a different DB server it is completed in less than 8 minutes).http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395769/c-asp-net-exception-some-times-only-during-long-database-operation. I am the only person accessing db; this is the only operation happening.

Comment: Add Tao has indicated, with the full recovery mode, you're essentially stuck in regards to logging.

If you're seeing such dramatically different results between two database servers, there may be something else at play with the DB server itself, ie. low memory, disk-bound processes, processor speed, disk speed, SQL/server activity, network connection between server and app, connection pooling setting, log file location, etc.

Just because you're the only person accessing the db doesn't mean that the server itself isn't bogged down :)

Comment: @Lijo : Insert data into table C in parts using insert into c select * from AandB WHERE ID <SOMETHING. Or you can take send output of a and b data as xml to stored procedure to insert bulk data. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SELECT INTO` with the `BULK_LOGGED` recovery model in order minimise the number of records written to the transaction log as described in Example B of the [INTO Clause documentation (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx):

```
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2008R2 SET RECOVERY BULK_LOGGED;
GO
-- Put your SELECT INTO statement here
GO
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2008R2 SET RECOVERY FULL;
```

**This is also required for bulk inserts** if you wish to have minimal impact on the transaction log as described in [Optimizing Bulk Import Performance (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190421.aspx):

> **For a database under the full recovery model, all row-insert operations that are performed during bulk import are fully logged in the transaction log.** For large data imports, this can cause the transaction log to fill rapidly. For bulk-import operations, minimal logging is more efficient than full logging and reduces the possibility that a bulk-import operation will fill the log space. **To minimally log a bulk-import operation on a database that normally uses the full recovery model, you can first switch the database to the bulk-logged recovery model.** After bulk importing the data, switch the recovery model back to the full recovery model.

*(emphasis mine)*

I.e. if you don't already set the database recovery model to `BULK_LOGGED` before performing a bulk insert then **you won't currently be getting the benefit of minimal transaction logging with bulk insers either** and so the transaction log won't be source of your slowdown.  (The `SqlBulkCopy` class doesn't do this for you automatically or anything)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use select into.
Try to take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191244.aspx

Comment: The database is in  full recovery model; it cannot be changed.. Is SELECT INTO usefull in such scenario?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2008 you do not need to return the data to the client/application before proceeding with a minimally logged operation. You can do it within the stored procedure immediately following your query that produces the result to be inserted to Table C.

See [Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx): Specifically "Using INSERT INTO…SELECT to Bulk Load Data with Minimal Logging"

**[Edit]:** Having since expanded your question to include that you are using the FULL recovery model, you therefore cannot benefit from minimally logged operations.

Instead you should concentrate your efforts on optimising your data insert process, than concern yourself with logging overhead.

Comment: Volume Of Data: 150,000 - Database : SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 0):

Can you give an example of the processing your procedure does?

Typically, I would think a set-based insert of 150,000 rows (no linked servers or anything) would take almost no time on most installations.

How long does just selecting the 150,000 rows with a query take?

Are you using a cursor and loop instead of a single `INSERT INTO C SELECT * FROM (some combination of A and B)`?

Is there any blocking which is causing the operation to wait for other operations to complete?

If your database is in full recovery model, it is going to log the operation - that's the point of using the database that way.  The database has been told to use that model and it's going to do that to ensure it can comply.

Imagine if you told the database that a column needed to be unique but it didn't actually enforce it for you!  It would be worth less than a comment on a post-it note which fell off a specification document!

Comment: Selecting 150,000 rows is very fast. Also, I am the only person accessing the database and this is the only operation happening. So i don't see a chance of blocking

Answer (score 0):

`Insert data into table C in parts using insert into c select * from AandB WHERE ID < SOMETHING. Or you can take send output of a and b data as xml to stored procedure to insert bulk data.`

Hope this will help you.